# How can I make a dynamic filtering in Nest JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs, nest

I have a commercial application and I want to make dynamic filtering, but I have different fields and I can't specify any field, can you help me?
You can send me articles about it

this is my controller

```
  @ApiOperation({ summary : "Filtering" })
  @Get('getFiltered')
  public async filtering(
    @Query() filterParams : any
  ) {
    return this.announsService.filtering(filterParams)
  }
```

this is my service

```
  public async filtering(
    filterParams : any
  ) {
    let { pricee, priceEnd, place, used, currency, date, field1, field2, field3 } = filterParams;

    const result = await this.announsRepo.find({
      where: [
        { 
          price : MoreThanOrEqual(pricee),
          place,
          used,
          currency: field1,
          publishedAt : date
        },
        {
          price : LessThanOrEqual(priceEnd),
          place,
          used,
          currency: field1,
          publishedAt : date
        },
        { 
          price: Between(pricee, priceEnd),
          place,
          used,
          currency: field1,
          publishedAt : date
        }
      ]})

    return {filterParams, result}
  }
```

Comment: What you are doing right now is filtering data. Sorting is showing data in an ascending or descending order. This can be done in most ORMs.

Comment: I need dymamic data

Comment: Have you considered GraphQL?

Comment: @shoaib30 no I haven't

Comment: @SharlShaboyan it may be an overkill but graphQL will allow you to select filter and paginate data dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe you can use something like this:

```
interface FilterParams = {
   ...
   [key: string]: string | number;
}
```